# Create and loop through a multi dimensional Array that doesn't start from zero in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I try to create a two-dimensional Array filled with Objects like this:

```
Array[5][1] = Objekt //start from 5 & 1 instead of 0 & 0 
Array[6][1] = Objekt    
Array[7][1] = Objekt    
Array[9][1] = Objekt //skipped 8   
Array[10][1] = Objekt 

Array[2][2] = Objekt  
Array[3][2] = Objekt  
Array[4][2] = Objekt  
Array[6][2] = Objekt //skipped 5
Array[7][2] = Objekt

Array[3][3] = Objekt
Array[4][3] = Objekt
Array[5][3] = Objekt
Array[6][3] = Objekt
Array[8][3] = Objekt //skipped 7
```

My problem is: I don't can start from zero so I can't use the push function. That's because It's a grid. The first index is the X, the 2nd the Y position of the grid cube. (Three.js)

That's the object:

```
var grid =
[   
    //line 1
    {x:5,z:1},
    {x:6,z:1},
    {x:7,z:1},
    {x:9,z:1},
    {x:10,z:1},

    //line 2
    {x:2,z:2},
    {x:3,z:2},
    {x:4,z:2},
    {x:6,z:2},
    {x:7,z:2},

    //line 3
    {x:3,z:3},
    {x:4,z:3},
    {x:5,z:3},
    {x:6,z:3},
    {x:8,z:3},

    //..
};
```

But how can I create a Array like the top example instead of an array like arr[0][0], arr[0][1], arr[0][2], arr[1][0], arr[1][1], .. ? Is it even possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What seems to be a problem?

Comment: @PM 77-1: The problem seems to be that I don't know how to create a Array like this.

Comment: You will need to do it by explicitly specifying index values. Like in your first example.

Comment: @PM 77-1: You mean like: arr = []; arr[5] = []; arr[5][1] = new Object(); arr[5][2] = new Object(); and so on for each one?

Answer (score 2):

Since your objects contain the information where you want to position them in the array, you can achieve this with a simple loop:

```
var newArray = [];

grid.forEach(function(obj) {
    if (!newArray[obj.x]) {
        newArray[obj.x] = [];
    }
    newArray[obj.x][obj.z] = obj;
});
```

Iterating over all objects is also pretty easy. `forEach` skips holes:

```
newArray.forEach(function(innerArray) {
    innerArray.forEach(function(obj) {
        console.log(obj);
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice one. Thank you, I didnt knew that !arr[index] works like typeof(arr[index]) != 'undefined'. You helped me a lot, thank you.

Comment: Well, technically `!newArray[obj.x]` simply converts the value of `newArray[obj.x]` to a boolean and negates the value. E.g. `!0` is `true` as well. However, since your array is either `undefined` at that position or an array, this check is safe to use here.